Cant find sparkContext when running pyspark features with Databricks spark instance using VSCode
I am using databricks using vscode. (used databricks-connect with vscode-extension).
I am able to get the spark session using DatabricksSession
from databricks.connect import DatabricksSession
spark = DatabricksSession.builder.getOrCreate()

and its works fine. python code is executed locally in my venv and spark code is executed in the spark cluster.
Problem as below
I am trying to use pyspark.ml.feature module
When I try to run the following code, it gives an assertion error that it the _active_spark_context is None
    from databricks.connect import DatabricksSession
    from pyspark.ml.feature import Word2Vec
    spark = DatabricksSession.builder.getOrCreate()
    word2vec = Word2Vec(vectorSize=100, minCount=0, inputCol="text", outputCol="word_vectors",)

It works fine if I run the same file on databricks notebook.
I am aware that I can't user sparkContext from Databricks session [source]
My expectation is that the execution context on databricks spark session should have been passed to pyspark.
Error signature
AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
File /Users/x/test_w2v.py:2
      1 from pyspark.ml.feature import StringIndexer, Word2Vec
----> 2 word2vec = Word2Vec(vectorSize=100, minCount=0, inputCol="text", outputCol="word_vectors",)

File ~/repos/x/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyspark/__init__.py:139, in keyword_only.<locals>.wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs)
    137     raise TypeError("Method %s forces keyword arguments." % func.__name__)
    138 self._input_kwargs = kwargs
--> 139 return func(self, **kwargs)

File ~/repos/x/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyspark/ml/feature.py:5970, in Word2Vec.__init__(self, vectorSize, minCount, numPartitions, stepSize, maxIter, seed, inputCol, outputCol, windowSize, maxSentenceLength)
   5964 """
   5965 __init__(self, \\*, vectorSize=100, minCount=5, numPartitions=1, stepSize=0.025, \
   5966          maxIter=1, seed=None, inputCol=None, outputCol=None, windowSize=5, \
   5967          maxSentenceLength=1000)
   5968 """
   5969 super(Word2Vec, self).__init__()
-> 5970 self._java_obj = self._new_java_obj("org.apache.spark.ml.feature.Word2Vec", self.uid)
   5971 kwargs = self._input_kwargs
   5972 self.setParams(**kwargs)

File ~/repos/x/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyspark/ml/wrapper.py:79, in JavaWrapper._new_java_obj(java_class, *args)
     75 """
     76 Returns a new Java object.
     77 """
     78 sc = SparkContext._active_spark_context
---> 79 assert sc is not None
     81 java_obj = _jvm()
     82 for name in java_class.split("."):

Unsure what am I missing


Please post the code and error as text, not a screenshot.
